# Charging a L-ion battery 3.7V/850mAh with terminal connectors

Tags: batteries, charging

How do I charge a battery with a connector as shown in this link:

https://uk.farnell.com/bak/lp-503759-is-3/battery-lithium-pol-3-7v-1300/dp/2077882?MER=bn_level5_4NP_LastViewed_1

Comment: Are you asking what the connector is? ...or asking what method is used to charge the battery? The charging methodology is fully described in the datasheet: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1666651.pdf?_ga=2.64895532.209863444.1558193424-920776000.1557601960

Comment: Siddharth - FYI although you describe the battery as 850mAh in the question title, you actually link to a 1350mAh battery in the main body of the question, so the title and the link contradict each other. Therefore we don't know if you have given the correct link for your actual battery. Please edit your question to fix whichever part is wrong (title / link). Also please update your question to explain what help you want *exactly*, as requested by *Jack Creasey*. Thanks.

Comment: The charger I'm looking for is for a Li-ion battery of 3.7V/850mAh as stated in the title. The link is just there to show you what the battery and connector look like. My question is: what kind of charger can I plug this kind of a connector into? I know that the following charger can be used for my battery: https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-Promethean-ActivSlate-FW7650L-Charger/dp/B01F9Y0BSW

However I can't see where the connector would go? At the most basic level how does one charge a battery with the kind of connector I have?

Answer (score 1):

Yellow wire is means temperature of battery.
Just you need red and black wires.
You need current source to charge battery current of about 85mA. Current source must have Voltage treshold of 4.2V.

Comment: Not sure why someone downgraded this, but the answer is technically correct.

Comment: @Ale..chenski - I was curious too. I *suspect* it might have been downvoted when it was still [revision 1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/439179/1) of the answer, which would have been far less useful. Personally I disagree about stating a C/10 charge current in the answer (I haven't seen that suggested in any Li-ion or LiPo datasheet I've used, and despite being safe there are other choices), and if the question is really about about the charge algorithm (see the comment from *Jack*) then it must be a duplicate (surely?!).

Comment: @SamGibson Of course, you can use more current, but then you should monitor the temperature of the battery, otherwise it becomes dangerous. If we charge the battery without temperature control, then it is better not to use large values of the charging current.

Comment: @Alexey - My point is that you have left yourself open to disagreement by stating a *specific* charge current (why not 50mA? why not 105.765mA? etc). Better is to refer to the battery datasheet, and follow the manufacturer's recommendation. Or explain your position about heating. Or almost anything, rather than mention a *specific* current, with no explanation! You didn't mention that 85mA is C/10 (if the question title is correct) - but if the title is wrong and the link is correct, and it's a 1350mAh battery, then you stating 85mA becomes difficult for readers to understand. See what I mean?

Comment: @SamGibson, charge at 0.1C is always safe, and if OP can't read specifications, this would be a right advise. Luckily, the OP link contains the battery datasheet (a very rare case), and it says "standard charge 650 mA". However, the concern about overheating is a bit misplaced .Given that the datasheet also specifies ESR as 120mOhm max, even with 1 A charging current the dissipation will be under 120 mW, and the battery of that size will hardly overheat.

Comment: @Ale..chenski "*charge at 0.1C is always safe*" Yes, I said that :-) but the answer doesn't explain that 85mA = C/10 (if it's 850mAh) nor that there are other options. Interestingly, 85mA isn't what I would recommend for much larger batteries, as it could be below the typical recommended 0.02C cut-off current. This comes back to needing to explain why 85mA was stated. I ran out of space in my last comment to make the same point as you - the datasheet (for the 1350mA battery) states a C/2 standard charge rate with no special temperature checking mentioned (other than operating temperature).